# Syntax error in lambda with if expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
basic_salary['dem_education_level_numeric']=basic_salary['dem_education_level'].apply(lambda x : 3 if (x == 'high'))
```

I am getting below error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<ipython-input-20-80adac538241>, line 1)
  File "<ipython-input-20-80adac538241>", line 1
    basic_salary['dem_education_level_numeric']=basic_salary['dem_education_level'].apply(lambda x : 3 if (x == 'high'))
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help

Comment: Where's `else` part?  `3 if (x == 'high') else ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Side note: `apply()` is deprecated since 2.3. It has been supplemented with direct call syntax: `(lambda x:<whatever>)(value)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to have a `if` inside a `lambda` statement, an `else` must also be defined. Every `lambda` statement must return something, even if it's `None`. Change your `lambda` statement to this, by returning `None` if `x` isn't `"high"`:

```
lambda x : 3 if x == 'high' else None # paralysis isn't necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda statements need to return something, and without an `else` clause the return may be ambiguous. Change to:

```
basic_salary['dem_education_level_numeric']=basic_salary['dem_education_level'].apply(lambda x : 3 if x == 'high' else 0)
```